# xvfb - where do I download the xvfb standalone package?

Tags: xvfb

I want to use xvfb to automate the process to create thumbnails images on urls from my site.

It is not clear where I should download a standalone xvfb application.
Where do I download the package?
How do I build the package?

Are there any other packages to create images of a rendered url on the linux server using php or shell scripting?

I am on Linux Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Tikanga)

Answer (score 3):

After some search, I find it's part of the XFree86 implementation of X11. http://ftp.xfree86.org/pub/XFree86/4.8.0/binaries/Linux-x86_64-glibc23/

*Update*: the above link is dead. If you're using a standard linux OS, try search xvfb with system package manager (e.g. apt or yum)

Comment: Is it no longer part of xorg e. g. modular xorg? I found this on an old slackware x86 build from ~2012 too.

Comment: @Drakes, if you're using a standard linux OS, try search xvfb with system package manager (e.g. apt or yum)

Answer (score 0):

`sudo yum install -y xorg-x11-server-Xvfb`

or

It's available on the Client, Workstation, and Server Optional Channels inside RHN: (Note the URLs here will prompt for your redhat support account)

https://rhn.redhat.com/network/software/packages/name_overview.pxt?package_name=xorg-x11-server-Xvfb&archIdList=&archLabelList=&search_subscribed_channels=yes